# How does Islam look on someone that leaves the religion

Tags: apostasy

Is it true when you leave islam that Islamic communitity must kill him or her?
And how does Islam treats ex-muslims??

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so that muslims people treat ex-muslim so badly, it can be but it's because he doesn't study Islam's behavior correctly.

Comment: @Ihasan Praditya It's exists a big ex-muslim movement in the west were they family isolate persons that are leaving Islam and becomming Ex-muslims